# Short story taking place on a toroidal planet or moon involving flying

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story that I remember reading, probably in Asimov's (but perhaps in Analog or F&SF), probably in the mid 1990s (unlikely to have been before 1985, or later than 2000).

The main features I remember of the story was that it took place on a toroidal planet or moon, and involved the main character (who was human or humanoid) becoming obsessed with building himself a pair of wings and flying through the atmosphere on the inside of the ring (where I guess the gravity would be much less).

There may have been an ominous and lonely feeling in the story.  The main character was quite alone (perhaps marooned), but there were hints of a large bird-like winged alien flying creature that could only be seen in the distance, and perhaps an ancient tower that the main character feels drawn to.

> In my (very hazy) memory: at the end of the story the character decides that jumping off the roof of the tower (which is on the inside of the ring) will let him achieve his goal of flying

Comment: I would like to read this! Hope you get an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe this story to be "Moonbow" by J. P. Boyd, which appeared in the May 1981 issue of Asimov's magazine. The toroidal planet had an intelligent avian species, and the planet's structure resulted in a lower surface gravity than its total mass would suggest; low enough that a human being could fly Icarus-style with artificial wings. There may have been a suggestion that the avian people had constructed the planet.
The issue's cover art was by George Angelini.
[image]

Comment: Available at the Luminist Archive here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZItMYHDIrXG_nnEDkoLDs1FV5JHRBJI3/view

Comment: Now I want to see the math for how gravity would work on such a planet. I know the inside of a spherical shell of a planet would have zero gravity (even very close to the interior "surface"), but it's not obvious to me what the interior of a toroidal planet would like, close to the surface. Given that Asimov is the author, I trust his description is at least a reasonable approximation.

Comment: @BenHocking _"by J. P. Boyd"_

Comment: @pipe It seems I forgot to look at the "fine print"! (OK, not that fine, I suppose.)

Comment: @BenHocking I'm relatively certain that such a planet, even if man-made somehow, could not exist without collapsing under its own weight.  Unless it's so small that describing it as a "planet" would be a serious stretch, e.g. a toroidal space station.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, yes, I'm fairly certain the substrate for such a planet would have to be made of "unobtainium", but if one assumes the planet was somehow created and stable, I'd be curious as the gravity gradients, especially near the interior but close to the surface of the planet. A question for physics.stackexchange.com, perhaps. After all, I remember many a physics problem, especially in E&M, involving infinite cylinders, and this at least seems a little less problematic than that!

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, it seems someone else has already asked! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101301/toroidal-planets

Comment: however @BenHocking the result there is "we don't know and nobody serious has bothered to figure it out"

Comment: Ben, it's trivial to provide an actual formulaic (ie, perfect) solution for the gravity near an infinitely long sausage of planet. (You can easily google it, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/326085/10319 )  However: the gravity of the surface of a donut planet is not solvable (it's like the "three body problem", you know?)  It can only be solved with computer simulations (ie, exactly as is the case with the "three body problem")  Interestingly, according to that one guy, nobody competent/serious has tried to do that - apparently!

Comment: Also, https://www.aleph.se/andart/archives/2014/02/torusearth.html by Anders Sandberg, which you can also find following those Physics.SE links.

Comment: Lots of YouTube videos on this. Search *donut planet*  https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=donut+planet